# eLisp recursive function

Tags: emacs, elisp

New to Lisp.  Trying to pass a list into a recursive function and do something with the first item in the list each time. This is the function so far:

```
(setq colors '(red blue green yellow orange pink purple))

(defun my-function (x)
  (if (> (length x) 0)
      (let ((c  (car x))
            c)
        (my-function x))))
```

Keep getting an error saying x is a void element.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: please fix your formatting, what you have now is unreadable. please also copy and paste the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I reformat your function, maybe you can see what you're doing wrong:

```el
(defun my-function (x)
  (if (> (length x) 0)  ; do nothing if list is empty
      (let ((c (car x)) ; bind c to (car x)
            c)          ; bind c to nil instead
                        ; c is never used
        (my-function x)))) ; recursively call function
                           ; with unmodified x
                           ; until the stack is blown
```

> Keep getting an error saying x is a void element.

I imagine you're calling `(my-function x)` with an undefined `x` instead of passing it your `colors` list with `(my-function colors)`, but that's certainly not your only problem.